# Generating Multiple Unit Tests With Junit

Tags: java, junit

I would like to know if it is possible to generate unit tests with Junit. All at once.
That is, the project is ready and I want to generate all the methods and classes of tests (at the same time)
Is there any script or command?

Comment: I don't think so.  Normally one writes the tests for each class at the same time as the class itself.  Once a project is "done" it's too big and too interconnected to test effectively, I think you'll have a huge mess on your hands.

Comment: Even if, that would make no sense. Usually, you have multiple tests for one method since you don't test all the behaviour of one method in one test since that would be rather unspecific. If you don't have any tests on a completed project, you're likely to be in a bad situation anyway.

Comment: The question isn't asking for a tool to generate JUnit tests; the question is asking if JUnit can generate tests.  This is objectively and straightforwardly answered and is not deserving of a close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the previous answers. There is no magic way to generate a unit test. If so, they wouldn't make much sense.

Anyway, there are tools which might help you on your way.

IntelliJ IDEA, which is one of the most common IDE for Java, allows you to generate a test class using a shortcut (I'm not sure about how far Eclipse or Netbeans has come with a similar feature). Optionally it allows you to generate stubbed methods:

[image: Generate test class]

The shortcut for this is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> while standing in the class you want to test. I use this feature all the time.

Optionally, IntelliJ can help you generate empty test methods, by ticking the boxes in the picture above. This results in the following code:

```
package se.test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class TestTest {

  @Test
  void someMethodToTest() {
  }

  @Test
  void someOtherMethodToTest() {
  }
}
```

This is a feature I have never used, since I think tests should have names explaining what they actually test. So for me, it is quite meaningless. However it is the closest I can think of as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, unit tests aren't generatable since everyone's business logic is different, and what everyone needs to validate and test are different.

It is on ***you***, the engineer, the person who wrote this code, to write appropriate and complete tests for the code to be sure it meets expectations.

Answer (score 2):

JUnit is not a test generator. It is a framework for **you** to write and run tests.